# In Salmon Run, what is the effect of playing when using an experience ticket?

Tags: splatoon-2

Ive picked up some experience tickets along with other bonuses in Salmon Run, but I'm not exactly sure how they work. When playing with the cash tickets, its obvious but not so much with experience tickets. What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 2):

When you are using a experience ticket, you cannot do anything with it because it only works in The Lobby to play 4v4 matches. However, having that bonus and going into Salmon Run, makes it not get used up.

Answer (score 0):

The experience tickets only work in multiplayer matches.